# rsync fails with intermittently with different error codes on the same command

Tags: rsync

I am running `rsync` for a huge server (100s of Gb), and got two failures that didn't seem to make sense:

```
3      Errors selecting input/output files, dirs
```

and

```
10     Error in socket I/O
```

The exact `rsync` command is `rsync -rtlzv --delete`. The same command can result in these errors on different runs (before completing). What might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue my target directory was on an external drive, and there is some instability in that drive's connection (I suspect it periodically re-mounts), leading to sudden failures of `rsync` at whatever step in the process happens to be running when this happens.

The solution for me is to manually re-mount the drive and try again (I haven't come up with a way to increase the mount drive stability, unfortunately).rsync -rtlzv --delete